# jquery.min has very long TTFB

Tags: jquery

I have noticed recently some plugins like Jetpack, Yoast and Wordfence in my WordPress admin take a long time to load. I investigated the issue in Chrome console and noticed the TTFB to load jquery.min is very long.

[image]

An example of a URL it is loading is https://c0.wp.com/c/5.7/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js - what is causing the long delay?

Comment: jquery.min.js doesn't have a high TTFB, admin-ajax.php does. A plugin or something is making an AJAX request that is very slow. You need to click on the request and view the details to see what's responsible. Look for the `action` parameter.

Comment: it says action: wordfence_loadIssues

Comment: There you go. The issue is Wordfence. You’ll need to speak to them to find out if this is unusual or what the issue might be.

Comment: The same issue is occurring with other plugins like Jetpack and Yoast. Could it be my server?

Comment: You're looking at the admin site. I'd guess that request is loading the data to be displayed on the page, possibly doing a few tests first, so it's not worth worrying about. Are you getting long TTFBs for front end pages?

Comment: Frontend pages are fine and load in 2 or 3 seconds.